# Auto-add 'requires' lines to Makefile.PL from dependencies used in a Catalyst application

Tags: perl, makefile, perl-module, catalyst

I've developed a Catalyst application without having regularly added dependencies to `Makefile.PL` using the `requires 'Module::Foo';` way. It was not a problem during development, but now I have to deploy. I have used a lot of modules, it is a pain to do this work.

Is there a common way to parse all the `.pm` files in `lib` directory and write it to the `Makefile.PL`? Is there a reason that each time we `use` a module, it is not automatically added to the `Makefile.PL`?

Does somebody would know a kind of Catalyst Helper or anything else that could make the job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Neil Bowers review: CPAN modules for getting module dependency information](http://neilb.org/reviews/dependencies.html) recommends [Module::Extract::Use](http://p3rl.org/Module%3a%3aExtract%3a%3aUse) and [Perl::PrereqScanner](http://p3rl.org/Perl%3a%3aPrereqScanner).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Dist::Zilla which has a plugin to detect your prerequisites

http://dzil.org/tutorial/prereq.html

Or you could roll your own and grep your code for `use` and `require` statements.

Comment: http://p3rl.org/Perl::PrereqScanner is the relevant part of Dist::Zilla, no need to install the whole monster. Please don't write another scanner, there are more than enough and you can't get the edge cases right.

Answer (score 0):

For simpler use case, [@climagic](https://twitter.com/climagic) recommends :

```
grep -rh ^use --include="*.pl" --include="*.pm" . | sort | uniq -c
```

as a solution which is *not perfect, but gives you a start on the Perl modules in use*.